VLAN Configuration without inter-vlan routing but with Internet access
I’m trying to set up multiple VLANs on my Cisco Catalyst 3850 switch and connect them to the internet using a TP-Link AX20/Asus RT-N12 router. I need this setup to have multiple isolated networks with different Ip ranges in a way that devices in each vlan cannot communicate with other vlans but they all have access to Internet.  However, the routers don't seem to support VLAN tagging (802.1Q), and I’m wondering if it’s possible to achieve this setup without needing a more advanced router.
My Current Setup:
Switch: Cisco Catalyst 3850 24T
VLANs created:
VLAN 10: 192.168.10.0/24
VLAN 20: 192.168.20.0/24
VLAN 30: 192.168.30.0/24

Each VLAN has an SVI configured with its respective gateway IP:
VLAN 10 SVI: 192.168.10.1
VLAN 20 SVI: 192.168.20.1
VLAN 30 SVI: 192.168.30.1

The routers do not support VLAN tagging or subinterfaces.
Its LAN IP is 192.168.1.1 (assigned manually) and is connected to a trunk/access port on the switch.
DHCP: DHCP pools are configured on the switch to assign IPs in the VLAN ranges automatically.
Problem:
Devices in each VLAN can communicate within their VLAN but they cannot access the internet.
I suspect the issue lies with the routers inability to recognize VLAN traffic. Since it doesn’t support VLAN tagging, it can only route traffic from a single subnet (VLAN 10 in this case).
just for test I even enabled Inter-VLAN routing on the switch using ip routing.
Question:

Is it possible to set up this configuration without replacing the router with a more advanced one that supports VLANs?
If yes, how can
I configure the switch and router to make it work?
If no, what would
be the simplest, cost-effective way to enable internet access for all
VLANs?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Let me
know if additional details are needed.
Thanks in advance!

I’m voting to close this question because it's a double post and there's already an answer on NE. https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86573/vlan-configuration-without-inter-vlan-routing-but-with-internet-access
